# Cant get a Diamond Shape in C right

Tags: c, shapes

I'm doing a c exercise to do a diamond shape with '#' using a funcion.
My code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
//Declare function
void losangle(int n);
//main
int main(void){
  int n;
  do {
    printf("Altura do triangulo: ");
    scanf("%d", &n );
  } while( n % 2 == 0);
  losangle(n);}
//function
void losangle(int n){
  int i, hashtag, spaces, j, spaces1, hashtag1;
//triangle
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(spaces = 0; spaces < (n-i); spaces++){
      printf(" ");}
    for(hashtag = 0; hashtag < (i+1);hashtag++){
      printf("# ");}
    printf("\n");}
//inverted triangle
  for(j = 0; j < (n - 1); j++){
    for(spaces1 = 0; spaces1 < (j+2); spaces1++){
        printf(" ");}
//not working !!!  
    for(hashtag1 = (n-1); hashtag1 > 0; hashtag1--){
      printf("# ");}
    printf("\n");
  }}
```

The output is this :

```
Losangle: 5
     # 
    # # 
   # # # 
  # # # # 
 # # # # # 
  # # # # 
   # # # # 
    # # # # 
     # # # #
```

What is making the '#' not decrementing in the bottom part ? Is this line  wrong (for(hashtag1 = (n-1); hashtag1 > 0; hashtag1--)) ?? Btw i also accept tips to improve the code efficiency.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through this code line by line.

Comment: yes, it should be `hastag1 = n-j-1` since you want to decrement the amount of # you are outputting

Comment: If it's an exercise, consider modularizing this a bit more. Divide the work into a function that draws a single line of a given length, and call that one repeatedly.

Take the habit of using `puts(s)`, or `printf("%s", s)` when you want to print a single string without formatting. Here you are dealing with string constants, so it's okay, but it is a security issue to use `printf` without a format argument.

I think you mean _losange_ too, but it could be a pun with triangle or los angeles, not sure.

Comment: Minor pet peeves that I can't ignore: the name of the shape is "lozenge" (not "losangle"), and the name of the symbol is "hash" or "number sign" (not "hashtag", which would be a tag that has that symbol as part of its syntax).

Comment: @init_js: How is using `printf` without a format argument (by which you probably mean just with a format string, but no further arguments) a security issue? The security issue is in not using string literals as format strings, where static analysis can't find the format mismatches.

Comment: I sign up right now on this community and i have to say you guys are awesome so many answers in a couple of minutes. My code is already working. Thank you. Now i'll try improve the code.

Comment: @mOehm: In cases where you're reading a string from something external to your program (from a user, a file, the network, etc.) and you want to display it... i.e.: `s = read_some_buffer(); printf(s);`, you may run into a situation where the string contains formatting sequences (e.g. `%s`, `%f` etc.) in which case you'd be retrieving garbage from the stack. Particularly problematic are the sequences like `%n` which tell printf to _write_ the number of characters so far, which could be used to rewrite a return address.

@rhymoid: and yes.. what you said, _lozenge_. excuse my French.

Comment: @mOehm: I agree though. if you can statically infer that the first argument to printf contains no formatting sequences, it's all good. just meant it's a good habit to form.

Comment: @init_js: I know all that, thanks. But none of the `printf` statements in the post exhibit that problem. No string comes from user input. Moreover, all strings are literals without format specifiers. `printf("\n")` is probably rendered more efficiently as `putchar('\n')`, but it is not harmful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issue:**

The inverted triangle `for` loop iterates from `n-1` to `0` every time, regardless of `j`'s value.

**Solution:**

Iterating between `n-1` to `j` will cause the number of hash symbols to decrease every iteration.

Change this line:

```
for(hashtag1 = (n-1); hashtag1 > 0; hashtag1--){
```

to

```
for(hashtag1 = (n-1); hashtag1 > j; hashtag1--){
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's already working now i'll try to improve the code a little bit more.

Comment: @m3k3r1 Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Milestone 1**

What's the high level logic of the program?

```
void getInutAndDrawDiamond()

int getTriangleHeight();
void drawDiamond(int height);

int main()
{
   getInutAndDrawDiamond();
   return 0;
}

void getInutAndDrawDiamond()
{
   int height = getTriangleHeight();
   drawDiamond(height);
}
```

with dummy implementations of `getTriangleHeight` and `drawDiamond`.

```
int getTriangleHeight()
{
   return 0;
}

void drawDiamond(int height)
{
}
```

**Milestone 2**

Add a proper implementation of  `getTriangleHeight`.

```
int getTriangleHeight()
{
   int height;
   int c;
   char const* prompt = "Enter the height of the triangle: ";

   printf("%s", prompt);
   while ( scanf("%d", &height) != 1 )
   {
      // Error reading the input.
      // Ignore rest of the line
      while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF );

      // If EOF is reached, exit.
      if ( c == EOF )
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Try reading again.
      printf("%s", prompt);
   }

   return height;
}
```

**Milestone 3**

Add the next level implementation of  `drawDiamond`, using couple of helper functions that have dummy implementations.

```
void drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(int height);
void drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(int height);

void drawDiamond(int height)
{
    drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(height);
    drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(height);
}

void drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
}

void drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
}
```

**Milestone 4**

Add the next level implementation of `drawUpperHalfOfDiamond` and `drawLowerHalfOfDiamond`, using dummy implementations of couple of helper functions.

```
void drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(int row);
void drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(int row);

void drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row )
   {
      drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(row);
   }
}

void drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row )
   {
      drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(row);
   }
}

void drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(int row)
{
}

void drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(int row);
{
}
```

**Milestone 5**

Add the next level implementation of `drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond` and `drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond`, using dummy implementations of a few helper functions.

```
int getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(int row);
void drawUpperHalfCell(int row, int col);

int getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(int row);
void drawLowerHalfCell(int row, int col);

void drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(int row)
{
   int cols = getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(row);
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col )
   {
      drawUpperHalfCell(row, col);
   }
}

void drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(int row)
{
   int cols = getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(row);
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col )
   {
      drawLowerHalfCell(row, col);
   }
}

int getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(int row)
{
   return 0;
}

void drawUpperHalfCell(int row, int col)
{
}

int getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(int row)
{
   return 0;
}

void drawLowerHalfCell(int row, int col)
{
}
```

**Milestone 5**

Add proper implementations of the last four functions -- left as an exercise to the reader.

**Complete program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getInutAndDrawDiamond();

int getTriangleHeight();
void drawDiamond(int height);

void drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(int height);
void drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(int height);

void drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(int row);
void drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(int row);

int getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(int row);
void drawUpperHalfCell(int row, int col);

int getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(int row);
void drawLowerHalfCell(int row, int col);

int main()
{
   getInutAndDrawDiamond();
   return 0;
}

void getInutAndDrawDiamond()
{
   int height = getTriangleHeight();
   drawDiamond(height);
}

int getTriangleHeight()
{
   int height;
   int c;
   char const* prompt = "Enter the height of the triangle: ";

   printf("%s", prompt);
   while ( scanf("%d", &height) != 1 )
   {
      // Error reading the input.
      // Ignore rest of the line
      while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF );

      // If EOF is reached, exit.
      if ( c == EOF )
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Try reading again.
      printf("%s", prompt);
   }

   return height;
}

void drawDiamond(int height)
{
   drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(height);
   drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(height);
}

void drawUpperHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row )
   {
      drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(row);
   }
}

void drawLowerHalfOfDiamond(int height)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row )
   {
      drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(row);
   }
}

void drawUpperHalfRowOfDiamond(int row)
{
   int cols = getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(row);
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col )
   {
      drawUpperHalfCell(row, col);
   }
}

void drawLowerHalfRowOfDiamond(int row)
{
   int cols = getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(row);
   for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col )
   {
      drawLowerHalfCell(row, col);
   }
}

int getNumberOfColumsForUpperHalfRow(int row)
{
   // TODO a proper implementation
   return 0;
}

void drawUpperHalfCell(int row, int col)
{
   // TODO a proper implementation
}

int getNumberOfColumsForLowerHalfRow(int row)
{
   // TODO a proper implementation
   return 0;
}

void drawLowerHalfCell(int row, int col)
{
   // TODO a proper implementation
}
```

**Concluding Remarks**

After implementing the last four functions properly, the program is very well structured to be able to diagnose problems easily by changing what gets called from `main`.

Comment: Damn I really understand better the code like this *.* Thank you.

Comment: @m3k3r1, it helps to take a step back and to spend time understanding the abstractions -- both the functionality and the data that you are dealing with.

Comment: @R Sahu I'm still in the basics in C language but i'll try your method to other exercises too. What are the advantages of having all this  functions besides the clarity ,more abstraction and more understanding code ?  It improves something under the hood ?

Comment: It helps you diagnose problems quickly. It allows you to test different aspects of the program quickly. It allows you to make improvements with minimal disruption to existing code. The program is aesthetically pleasing :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Some crazy complicated answers have been posted.
Here it is in one loop, one printf, and one variable (other than the Width input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int w = 9;
    int l;

    for(l=0; l < w; ++l)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n",
            abs(w/2 - l)+abs((2*l+1)-(2*l+1>w)*2*w),
            abs((2*l+1)-(2*l+1>w)*2*w),
            "# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**[Link to IDEOne Code](http://ideone.com/DvFY7H)**